# Creating a fixed background using tkinter

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using tkinter when and trying to set up a window with a background image.  In some of the processes I have a frame that fills up with checkboxes so I created a scrollbar so the user can see all the options.  The problem is the scroll bar also moves the background image of the canvas.  Is there a way I can fix the image to not move or somehow move the frame by itself.

code is

```
def canvasScroll():
    canvas = gui.createCanvas() 
    fFrame = gui.createNewFrame()

    scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand= True)
    canvas.create_window((150,50),window = fFrame, anchor='nw', tags = "frame")
    gOb.change_canvas(canvas)
    fFrame.bind("<Configure>", gui.scroll)

    gOb.change_scrollbar(scrollbar)
    gOb.change_frame(fFrame)

def createCanvas():
    canvas = Canvas(root,height = _h, width = _w,highlightthickness = 0)
    canvas.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand='yes')
    canvas.create_image(-200,-200,image=bground,anchor='nw')  
    return canvas
def createNewFrame():
    frame = Frame(root,height = _h, width = _w,background='white')
    frame.pack()
    return frame
```

Just to clear things up, these guys are all part of a class name gui and gOb is an object that hold several gui objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea - it's kind of kludgy, but it would work.  Every time the scrollbar scrolls, shift the background image's position so it appears to stay in the same place:

Tag your image so you can access it later:

```
canvas.create_image(-200,-200,image=bground,anchor='nw',tags="background")
#                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Make your scrollbar call a function that you define:

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=scrollCallback)
```

Define your scroll callback:

```
def scrollCallback(*args):
    canvas.yview(*args)
    # Arrange for your background image to move so it appears to stay in the same position as the canvas scrolls.
```